# how to work with multiple coincident panel controls in VS 2008 windows forms

Tags: .net, visual-studio, winforms

in VS 2008, I am attempting to design a windows form that is similar to a set of property pages but uses a TreeView to select the page rather than a TabControl.  An example of this design is the Options dialog in VS 2008 itself.  There are two reasons I want to do this:  1. I prefer the look and feel;  2. I want to give users the ability to add child nodes to the TreeView.

I am using multiple Panel controls to contain the controls for each "property page".  These panels will all be coincident on the form, i.e. overlapping each other.  I am finding that the VS UI designer is not very user-friendly when I do this; I can select each panel easily enough, but all the controls inside the panel are visible at the same time, leading to a jumbled mess.  Working with a TabControl is much easier, as you can select a tab and only see the controls that you've placed onto that tab.

Is there a different approach that will make this easier for me, or do I have to make do with a TabControl?  TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get behavior similar to the `TabControl` where each tab gives you a different designer canvas on which to place controls, you will need to write a [designer for your control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h51z5c0x.aspx) that provides the tabbing interaction when in the Forms designer. However, if you want to avoid this, you could take the approach we use in a similar situation and make each tab page its own `UserControl`, then add them as tabs in the constructor of your main tabbed control.

This allows you to design each tab individually, avoiding the overlapping issue you currently face.